# Sort List in ascending order in C ++ with bubble sort

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

This is a people registration system, in option 1 I add the age and the name of the person I need my list to be sorted automatically with bubble sort by age in ascending order after the registration and that in option 2 show the list sorted through of the age and not the order that was registered.

I have no idea how to do it: /

Can anybody help me?

Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int contadorid = 0;

template<class T>
class Node
{
    T element;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(T element, Node *n)
    {
        this->element = element;
        this->next = n;
    }
    Node(T element)
    {
        this->element = element;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    T getElement()
    {
        return this->element;
    }
    void setElement(T element)
    {
        this->element = element;
    }
    Node* getNext()
    {
        return this->next;
    }
    void setNext(Node *next)
    {
        this->next = next;
    }

};

template<class T>
class List
{
private:
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
    int count;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = tail = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return head == 0;
    }

    void lista_push_back(T element)
    {
        bool empty = this->isEmpty();
        Node<T> *node = new Node<T>(element);
        node->setNext(NULL);
        if (empty)
            this->head = node;
        else
            this->tail->setNext(node);
        this->tail = node;
        this->count++;
    }

    //percorre e mostra na tela
    void percorre_list()
    {
        Node<T>* current = this->begin();

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << current->getElement() << endl;
            current = current->getNext();
        }
    }

    Node<T>* begin()
    {
        return this->head;

    }
    Node<T>* end()
    {
        return this->tail;

    }

    unsigned int size()
    {
        return this->count;
    }

};

string adicionapacote()
{
    int qos;
    char conteudo[1024];
    char pacote[1024];

    cout << "Age\n";

    cin >> qos;
    cout << "Name\n";
    cin >> conteudo;

    contadorid = contadorid + 1;

    sprintf(pacote, "%d\t%d\t%s", contadorid, qos, conteudo);

    return (pacote);

}

int main()
{
    List<string> *L = new List<string>();
    string pacotao;
    while (1)
    {

        cout << endl;
        cout << "1 - Add" << endl;
        cout << "2 - View" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Dump" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Exit" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        int op;
        cin >> op;

        switch (op)
        {
            case 1:
            {

                pacotao = adicionapacote();
                L->lista_push_back(pacotao);
                //L->dumpqos();
                break;

            }
            case 2:
            {
                L->percorre_list();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {

                cout << "Bye" << endl;
                return (0);

            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give us some sample input. What would the expected output be? With the code you posted, what is the actual output? What have you tried to solve this? Giving an assignment description, saying "I have no idea how to do it" and then dumping code makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: Please only tag the relevant language.

Comment: You could search the internet for "C++ linked list bubble sort ascending" to get some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You never did the sort.

```
    pacotao=adicionapacote();
    L->lista_push_back(pacotao);
```

Instead of pushing to back, you might want to basically do an insertion sort and insert at the correct location.